# Have a problem in auth user "First argument "email" must be a valid string"

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3

I try to validate a sign up form and auth user email and password using firebase

```
    export class SignupPage {

signupForm :FormGroup;
user_name :AbstractControl;
user_email :AbstractControl;
acc_type: AbstractControl;
user_password:AbstractControl;
pushPage: any;
params: Object;
submitAttempt: boolean = false;
emailRegx: any;
label: any = {}; 


user = {} as User;


constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams 
,public formbuilder:FormBuilder,  public alertCtrl: AlertController, private 
afauth: AngularFireAuth 
) {


  this.signupForm = formbuilder.group({
  user_name: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.maxLength(30), 
  Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z ]*'), Validators.required])],
  user_email: ['', Validators.required],
  user_password: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.maxLength(40), 
  Validators.required])],
  acc_type: ['', Validators.required]

  });




 }


 ionViewDidLoad() {
  console.log('ionViewDidLoad SignupPage');
 }

showAlert() {
  let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
  title: 'Great!',
  subTitle: 'We about to Verfiy Your Accout verfiy with 4546!',
  buttons: ['Let\'s verfiy']
});
alert.present();
}

openLoginPage(){

this.navCtrl.push(LoginPage)
}



 creatAccount(){

 this.submitAttempt = true;

 if(!this.signupForm.valid){


 }
 else {
    console.log("success!")
    this.showAlert()

    this.navCtrl.push(EmailverPage)

 }

 }


  async register(user: User){
    try{
      const result = await 
      this.afauth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.user_email , 
      user.user_password)
     console.log(result);
    }

  catch(e) {

  console.error(e)

    }
  }


 }
```

htmlcode

```
         <ion-grid>

        <ion-row>
        <ion-col text-center     col-4 float-end        >
        <p class="pagetitle">Create Account</p>
        </ion-col>
       </ion-row>  

       <ion-row>
       <ion-col col-12 pager> 

            <form  class="signupForm" [formGroup]="signupForm">

              <ion-item class="input1">
                <ion-label floating>
                    <ion-icon name="person"></ion-icon> 

                  Full Name</ion-label>
                <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="user_name" 
           formControlName="user_name" 
          [class.invalid]="!signupForm.controls.user_name.valid && 
           (signupForm.controls.user_name.dirty || submitAttempt)"></ion- 
          input>
              </ion-item>
              <ion-item *ngIf="!signupForm.controls.user_name.valid  && 
             (signupForm.controls.user_name.dirty || submitAttempt)">
                  <p>Please enter a valid name.</p>
              </ion-item>

              <ion-item class="">
                <ion-label floating>
                    <ion-icon name="mail"></ion-icon> 

                  Email</ion-label>
                <ion-input  formControlName="user_email"  
               [(ngModel)]="user_email" pattern=""  type="Email" 
               [class.invalid]="!signupForm.controls.user_email.valid && 
            (signupForm.controls.user_email.dirty || submitAttempt)"></ion- 
           input>

            </ion-item>
            <ion-item *ngIf="!signupForm.controls.user_email.valid  && 
                 (signupForm.controls.user_email.dirty || submitAttempt)">
                <p>Please enter a valid email.</p>
            </ion-item>

            <ion-item> 
              <ion-label floating>
                <ion-icon name="checkbox"> </ion-icon>
                Account type </ion-label>
              <ion-select interface="popover" formControlName="acc_type" 
             name="acc_type"  [(ngModel)]="acc_type" 
             [class.invalid]="!signupForm.controls.acc_type.valid && 
             (signupForm.controls.acc_type.dirty || submitAttempt)">
                <ion-option value="1" selected="true"> Client </ion-option>
                <ion-option value="2"> Company </ion-option>
              </ion-select>
            </ion-item>

            <ion-item *ngIf="!signupForm.controls.acc_type.valid  && 
              (signupForm.controls.acc_type.dirty || submitAttempt)">
                <p>Please Select Your Account Type.</p>
            </ion-item>


            <ion-item>
                <ion-label floating>
                  <ion-icon name="lock"></ion-icon> 
                  Password
                </ion-label>
                <ion-input   type="password" [(ngModel)]="user_password" 
                 name="user_password" formControlName="user_password" 
                [class.invalid]="!signupForm.controls.user_password.valid && 
               (signupForm.controls.user_password.dirty || submitAttempt)"> 
              </ion-input>
              </ion-item>
              <ion-item *ngIf="!signupForm.controls.user_password.valid  && 
             (signupForm.controls.user_password.dirty || submitAttempt)">
                  <p>Please enter a valid email.</p>
              </ion-item>

              <ion-item class="input2">

                <button class="regButton" type="submit" ion-button full 
             round  (click)="register(user)" >Sign Up</button>

              </ion-item>
          </form>
                        </ion-col>
         </ion-row>
        <ion-row>
         <ion-col col-12 float-end      >
          <p style="text-align:center;color: aliceblue;"> Already have an 
        account? <a  (click)="openLoginPage()"> Log in </a></p>

           </ion-col>
          </ion-row>
      </ion-grid>



        </ion-content>
```

When I try it I get this console message:

> code: "auth/argument-error", message: "createUserWithEmailAndPassword failed: First argument "email" must be a valid string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `signupForm.value` to access form value. Next, get user email with `signupForm.value.user_email`. Do the same thing to get password value.
In fact, `user.user_email` is not a string.

All code :

```
async register() {
    try {
        if (this.signupForm.valid) {
            const values = this.signupForm.value;
            const result = await this.afauth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(values.user_email, values.user_password);
            console.log(result);
        }
    } catch(e) {
        console.error('error: ', e);
    }
}
```

You don't need yout `User` object. Besides, your user object doesn't contain `user_email` and `user_password` field.

Comment: How I can send more than argument in this function createUserWithEmailAndPassword() ?

Comment: Read the [doc here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#createUserWithEmailAndPassword)
This function takes two arguments, email and password and it returs a promise. What do you want to do with more arguments ?

Comment: I want to sign up with more data and return it when user sign in

Comment: You can't do this with `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` function. You can only pass an email and a password. Only these two fields are in database. If ou want more data when user subscribe, create `<input type="text / number / email">` with formControlName and get value thanks to `signupForm.values.FORM_CONTROL_NAME` (same process than get `email` and `password`)